# Troubleshooting Invalid Metric Filter Pattern Error in Terraform for AWS CloudWatch Log Metric Filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm encountering an error while trying to configure an AWS CloudWatch Log Metric Filter using Terraform. My goal is to create a metric filter that captures specific log data based on the level and logger fields. However, I keep getting an "Invalid metric filter pattern" error, and I'm unsure how to correct the pattern syntax.

Here's my Terraform configuration:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_count_metric_filter" {
  name           = "logGroupCount"
  pattern        = "{ $.level = * } { $.logger = <*> }"
  log_group_name = "myLogGroup"

  metric_transformation {
    name      = "logErrorCount"
    namespace = "logSpace"
    value     = "1"
    dimensions = {
      level  = "$.level"
      logger = "$.logger"
      #      message = "$.message"
    }
  }
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error: putting CloudWatch Logs Metric Filter (logGroupCount: InvalidParameterException: Invalid metric filter pattern
with module.data-retention.aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter.log_count_metric_filter
on <> line 21, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_count_metric_filter":
```

I've tried several variations of the pattern(`pattern = "{$.level $.logger}"`
), such as removing commas, changing the structure, but I keep encountering the same error. I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly format this pattern according to AWS CloudWatch Logs filter pattern syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that will work:

```
pattern = "{ ($.level = *) && ($.logger = *) }"
```

Take a look that tutorial for filters and pattern Syntax: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html